# Move contents of UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar

I found through another question on here how to change the height of UINavigationBar using a category:

```
#import "UINavigationBar+Taller.h"
@implementation UINavigationBar (Taller)
- (CGSize)sizeThatFits:(CGSize)size {
    CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width,100); //exaggerated height 
    return newSize;
}
@end
```

That works brilliantly.

Is there a way to move the title and navigation buttons up? They are aligning to the bottom of the new size. I want to put something into the bottom of the navigation bar.

Private methods are ok since this isn't going to be an app store candidate.

[image: example]

Answer (score 0):

To change the vertical offset for the title:

```
CGFloat yourOffset = 5.0; //whatever value you need
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleVerticalPositionAdjustment:yourOffset forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

To make the button a bit higher or lower

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
```

Another (more flexible) better approach would be to create a subclass of UINavigationBar
 and override layoutSubviews, placing your views in the correct place.